# How to pass an object to formick form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function that passes a student as a parameter

```
function EditStudentFrom  (student)  {

  var firstName = student.firstName;
   console.log(student)
  return(
    
  <Formik
      
    initialValues={{studentId: student.studentId, firstName: firstName, lastName: "", email: "", gender: "" }}
    enableReinitialize={true}
    validate={(values) => {
      const errors = {};

      if (!values.firstName) {
        errors.firstName = "First name required";
      }
      if (!values.lastName) {
        errors.lastName = "Last name required";
      }

      if (!values.email) {
        errors.email = " Email required";
      } else if (
        !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(values.email)
      ) {
        errors.email = "Invalid Email address";
      }

      if (!values.gender) {
        errors.gender = "Gender required";
      } else if (
        !["MALE ", "male", "female", "FEMALE"].includes(values.gender)
      ) {
        errors.gender = "Gender most be ( MALE , male , FEMALE, female )";
      }

      return errors;
    }}
    onSubmit={(student, { setSubmitting }) => {
      editStudent(student.studentId,student).then(() => {
      // props.onSuccess();

        setSubmitting(false);
      });
    }}
  >
    {({
      values,

      errors,

      touched,

      handleChange,

      handleBlur,

      handleSubmit,

      isSubmitting,

      submitForm,
      isValid,

      /* and other goodies */
    }) => (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        
        <Input
          style={inputMargin}
          name="firstName"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          value={values.firstName}
          placeholder="First name"
        />

        {errors.firstName && touched.firstName && (
          <Tag style={tagStyle}>{errors.firstName}</Tag>
        )}
        <Input
          style={inputMargin}
          name="lastName"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          value={values.lastName}
          placeholder="Last name"
        />
        {errors.lastName && touched.lastName && (
          <Tag style={tagStyle}>{errors.lastName}</Tag>
        )}
        <Input
          style={inputMargin}
          type="email"
          name="email"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          value={values.email}
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        {errors.email && touched.email && (
          <Tag style={tagStyle}>{errors.email}</Tag>
        )}
        <Input
          style={inputMargin}
          name="gender"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          value={values.gender}
          placeholder="Gender"
        />
        {errors.gender && touched.gender && (
          <Tag style={tagStyle}>{errors.gender}</Tag>
        )}

        <Button
          onClick={() => submitForm()}
          type="submit"
          disabled={isSubmitting | (touched && !isValid)}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    )}
  </Formik>
  
  )};              

export default EditStudentFrom;
```

I know the student object is getting pass to the function because I can log the student and if a put a break point in the `console.log` line I can see the initial value of `firstName` to be the first name of the student [image: You can see it here]

But if I put the break point pass the `<formik>` line now the student object is `undefined` [image: See it here]

I want the initial values to be the ones coming from the student object to make an `Edit` form.

Comment: Did you really mean to tag Java, not just Javascript?

Comment: no, sorry just edited the java tag out

Answer (score 0):

Your function is a component function and the parameter that you take from it is an object, you have to extract the student from it.

**object destructuring:**

```
 export const EditStudentFrom = ({ student }) =>
```